# Why WSO2 Send Mediator doesn't wait for response?

Tags: wso2, soa, wso2-esb

I have a WSO2 ESB-4.6.0 proxy that calls another proxy that calls an webservice.

```
Proxy1 --> Proxy2 --> Endpoint
```

If I directly call the second proxy via soapUI, the response is correctly returned and printed, but if I call the first proxy, then an blank body is returned.
In the ESB log, the outSequence of the Proxy1 is printed before the outSequence of the Proxy2.
Seems like the Send mediator present in the inSequence of the Proxy1 is making an asynchronous call to the Proxy2.
I've tried to replace the Send mediator by the Callout mediator, but the result is the same.

Follow [this](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining/) tutorial, but it didn't works also.

How to forward the response for the Proxy2 to the caller?
Please help. It's killing me!

**EDIT**

Problem solved! I was using a wrong port to specify the serviceURL parameter for Callout mediator.

**EDIT**

The current proxies configuration:

Proxy1 (calling Proxy 2 - ManageWorkforce):

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="GetAppointmentSchedulePortalReqCS" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <xslt key="conf:ManageWorkforce/xslt/GetAppointmentSchedulePortalReqCS_Request.xsl"/>
            <header name="Action" value="getAppointment"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="https://localhost:9443/services/ManageWorkforce"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <xslt key="conf:ManageWorkforce/xslt/GetAppointmentSchedulePortalReqCS_Response.xsl"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL key="conf:ManageWorkforce/GetAppointmentSchedulePortalReqCS.wsdl" />
</proxy>
```

Proxy 2 (calling Proxy3 -GetAppointmentPeopleProvCS):

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ManageWorkforce" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <switch source="get-property('Action')">
                <case regex="getAppointment">
                    <callout serviceURL="https://localhost:8243/services/GetAppointmentPeopleProvCS" action="getAppointment">
                        <source xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
                        <target xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
                    </callout>
                </case>
                <!-- another cases -->
                <default/>
            </switch>
            <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <header name="To" action="remove"/>
            <send/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <drop/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL key="conf:ManageWorkforce/ManageWorkforce.wsdl"/>
    </publishWSDL>
</proxy>
```

Proxy 3 (calling the service -GetAppointment):

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="GetAppointmentPeopleProvCS" transports="http https" serviceGroup="" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <endpoint key="GetAppointment"/>
        <inSequence>
            <xslt key="conf:ManageWorkforce/xslt/GetAppointmentPeopleProvCS_Request.xsl"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <xslt key="conf:ManageWorkforce/xslt/GetAppointmentPeopleProvCS_Response.xsl"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Final endpoint (service):

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="GetAppointment">
    <address uri="http://10.13.6.75:9764/services/GetAppointment" />
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mediators to invoke web services. Those are [Callout Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Callout+Mediator) and [Call Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Call+Mediator). The Callout mediator performs a blocking call and the Call Mediator performs a non-blocking call.

So, you should use Call mediator if you consider about performance. It's availble in ESB 4.8.0.

There are two [samples](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Invoking+Web+Services) for these in wiki docs.

There is another [sample](http://dushansview.blogspot.com/2013/09/upcoming-esb-features-iterate-and.html) for Call Mediator from Dushan's blog. This has more complex mediators, but you can try out.

This is just a quick answer.

I hope this helps.

Thanks!

Comment: But the waiting with call mediator does not work in iterate mediator. How to do it correcty?

Answer (score 1):

Proxy1 waits for the response from Proxy2 even you use the send mediator. 
outSequence of the Proxy1 should not get executed before the execution of outSequence of Proxy2.

Switch to Callout Mediator is *not* the ideal solution for this.
I think there should be something wrong with the proxy configuration.

If you can post the proxy configuration here, we might be able to give you a help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The Send Mediator does a non-blocking request to the specified URI you informed and then redirects you to outSequence(success) or to the faultSequence(error) depending on the response you got from the request. If you want to stay in the inSequence after making a request to a specific URI you can use the [Call Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/call-Mediator/) instead.